# MobileFirst7.1 Analytics - How to log custom analytics

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

How to log custom analytics? - Our Mobile App have several modules and each module is a Adapter, so in Analytics we really get very good details like what modules are used more by our users.

But we have one modules which is not an adapter but it is responsive web site which runs in inAppBrowser and we are misses the hit count for this module. Is there any way I can get this count using some custom analytics logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this blog post can help you:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/02/15/howto-send-custom-data-to-the-mobilefirst-analytics-server-from-adapters-or-any-java-application/

It describe how send custom data to analytics backend.